# JQuery append with Backbone variable scope

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a file, `test.html`, and I am appending another file, `appended.html` to it for various reasons.  The file `appended.html` has javascript in it, and I am referencing a function, `appendedFn`, defined in `appended.html` within a function in `test.html`, `testFn`.

This all works fine, but I just started implementing a Backbone router, and one of my router's routes calls the `testFn`, but for some reason I get a **ReferenceError** when `testFn` calls `appendedFn`, but ONLY when `testFn` is called from the router.  It says `appendedFn is not defined`, and I think this has something to do with maybe the router not having access to the content that I appended?

It looks approximately like this:

**test.html:**

```
function testFn() {
    $('#someObj').append(anotherObj); //anotherObj contains the contents of appended.html
    appendedFn(); //defined in appended.html
}
```

**router.js:**

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {}, //routes
goSomewhere: function() {
    testFn();
}
```

**Edit:** I can successfully call `testFn` from inside `test.html`.
Also, when I print out the div to which I appended `appended.html` (before I try calling `appendedFn`), it correctly prints the appended html and javascript.  For some reason, when I call `testFn` from the router, the html and javascript is loaded (as evidenced by the printed div contents), but it cannot access any of the appended contents (not the html or the javascript of `appended.html`).

Thank you for all the replies, I realize this may be a very confusing post, but I've been trying to work it out for a whole ton of hours and I can't figure it out.

Comment: hard to say without more information, but I'd guess that you're executing that method in the router _before_ the additional file has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

That's not Backbone's issue.inserted script tag by jQuery works as usual javascript execution.

```
(function(){
  $("body").append('<script>function test(){console.log("say hi")}</script>');
  test(); // outputs "say hi"
})()
```

There are 2 possibilities that I can think of why you can't call the method.

- You do not have the method in `anotherObj`

  check You have the method in `anotherObj` when you `append` to the DOM.
- You have the method. but it's in a scoped area.

  when you define new variable `var something` in a function, it will be scoped variable which cannot be accessed from outer code.